# Selected value of dropdown list does not change in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, database, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdown list in asp.net and it has data binded to it. Here it is:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="dPrereq1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" 
        DataTextField="FullName" DataValueField="FullName">
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT [CourseCode]+ ' ' + [CourseNumber] as 
        FullName FROM [CourseTable] ORDER BY [FullName]">
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

This dropdown list has values like "`CS 100", "CS 200`" etc. in it. Then ihave the following piece of code in my button click event:

```
 if (pCourseCode != "")
 {
     cbPreq1.Checked = true;
     dPrereq1.Enabled = true;
     string prereq=pCourseCode + " " + pCourseNumber;
     dPrereq1.SelectedValue = prereq;
 }
```

When i debug, i see that prereq becomes "CS 100", and which already exists in the dropdown list. But while debugging i saw that in the line `"dPrereq1.SelectedValue = prereq;"` the selected value of the dropdown list dPrereq1 does not change, it shows "". And so i get the error saying that:

`'dPrereq1' has a SelectedValue which is invalid because it does not exist in the list of items. Parameter name: value.`

Why cannot i set the value of dropdown list to "CS 100", but it stays as ""? Can anyone help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem: it looks like the issue was a space character.

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting it like below:

```
dPrereq1.Items.FindByValue(prereq).Selected = true
```

Comment: thanks, i tried it but dPrereq1.Items.FindByValue(prereq) returns null even though i see "CS 100" in the dropdown list. Am i filling the dropdown list wrongly?

Comment: can you give me the full code of your page? only then I can tell where the problem would be.

Comment: thanks, but i found the problem it looks like the problem was jus a space character

Comment: Ok. please answer this question yourself and tick it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, while adding new item to database, i accidentally put a space, i fixed it